# Как в запросе выбрать запись из одной таблицы по признаку из другой?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица `RECORDS`. На нее ссылается другая таблица `ASSESSMENT`по FK столбец `RECORD_ID` на `RECORDS.ID`. Одной записи в `RECORDS` может соответствовать несколько записей в `ASSESSMENT`. В `ASSESSMENT` есть также столбец `COLOR`, который в свою очередь ссылается на таблицу `DICTIONARY`. В DICTIONARY каждому `COLOR` соответствует приоритет `COLOR.priority`.

Как я могу извлечь для заранее известного ID записи из таблицы `RECORDS` одну запись из `ASSESMENT` с наименьшим значением приоритета цвета?

Например: имеем запись в `RECORD`

```
create table records (id) as 
    select 1 from dual
```

, ей соответствуют две записи в `ASSESMENT`:

```
create table assessment (id, record_id, color) as
    select 1, 1, 'red'   from dual union all
    select 2, 1, 'blue ' from dual
```

, а в таблице `DICTIONARY` дано:

```
create table dictionary (color, priority) as 
    select 'red',   1 from dual union all
    select 'blue',  2 from dual union all
    select 'green', 3 from dual
```

Нужно получить только запись с наименьшим значением приоритета, то есть у которой `RECORD_ID = 1`, `COLOR='red'`

Эту запись потом нужно будет соединить с другими, то есть обернуть это все в `JOIN`.

Comment: Join в CTE, нумерация в нужном порядке, выбор записей с номером 1.

Comment: Выберите **одну** СУБД. Удалите лишний тег. И вместо вербального описания выложите форматированным кодом CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO с примером данных и требуемым ответом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select r.id, a.color
from records r
cross apply (
    select max (a.color) keep (dense_rank first order by prio) color
    from assessment a, dictionary d
    where a.record_id = r.id 
    and   d.color = a.color ) a;

        ID COLOR
---------- -----
         1 red
```

С тестовыми данными [на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3ec975f63c7a3b47760b890bce494aac). Для [версий 11g и старше](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7bcf6ea35ec344e12921df1089193898).